# SQL foreign keys and referencing other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying link two tables together using a foreign key. One table is users, the other is userInfo. When I delete a user I also want to delete their info as well. When I delete a user from the users table their entry in usersInfo is still there. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
userid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
userlevel INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
rating int,
organization int(1),
timestamp varchar(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

Here is my table for userinfo. Yes, I know it could be in the same table. I'm just doing this for an easy example.

```
CREATE TABLE usersInfo(
userid int  auto_increment NOT NULL,
userlocation varchar(50),
about varchar(300),
userkeywords varchar(150),
FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES users(userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

---

Edit - problem solved. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Added `TYPE = InnoDB` at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Works fine for me if you remove the comma after `timestamp varchar(20) NOT NULL` in the first query. What MySQL version is this? Are these by any chance MyISAM tables, which don't do foreign key relationships, but which don't throw an error if you declare a foreign-key relationship either?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just assumed it was Innodb by default. How can I check?

Comment: What's your MySQL version? The default was MyISAM until MySQL 5.5.5 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html) and you're not specifying an engine in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, so if you're using anything below 5.5.5 these are MyISAM tables. To confirm this, you can also use a `SHOW TABLES` query to see the engine used for your existing tables.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it to work. I added a Type= INNODB; and it's now deleting properly.

Comment: You're welcome! I posted the solution as an answer, I'd appreciate it if you could accept that answer if this fixed your problem :) Happy coding!

Comment: @user1104854: Use `ENGINE = ...`, not `TYPE = ...` (that's old syntax and I think it's deprecated).

Comment: Another thing is that since ythe tables have a `1:1` relationship, the 2nd table (`userinfo`) that depends on the first, should not have the `userid` as auto-increment.

Comment: @ypercube If usersInfo.userid is a foreign key will it automatically be assigned the values of users.userid? It's auto incrementing because when a new user is added, a row for their info is also added, thus they both have the same userid.

Comment: That's what I mean, when you add a row in `userinfo` you are overridding the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute and assigning the `userid` from the `user` table. You are never going to need the auto_increment in `userinfo`, only in `user`

Comment: @ypercube So does that mean a foreign key automatically take the value of a primary key it references? In this case will usersInfo.userid take the value of users.userid assuming I remove the auto_increment?

Comment: No, it doesn't take automatically any value. You will be: 1.inserting a row in `users` table. 2.get the (auto) generated userid value and 3.use it for inserting into `userinfo`.

Comment: Oh, ok. So just use last_entry or something similar and insert that value?

Comment: [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ENGINE=INNODB` to these `CREATE TABLE` statements to ensure they're InnoDB tables. MySQL versions below 5.5.5 will default to MyISAM, which does not support foreign-key relationships, but which will not throw an error if you define a foreign-key relationship either.